# Can a Column be Nullable, Unsigned and a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database

I have several tables which I want to reference to a particular table `tools`. I have multiple foreign keys assigned to this table. Some times, these foreign keys may not have values but sometimes they do.

I want to know if it is possible for a column be `nullable`, `unsigned` and a `foreignkey` at the same time? Am I sounding sensible or am I completely wrong?  Just for the information, I'm using MySQL if it is platform dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem to do so. Are you getting any errors when you try?

Comment: I'm dealing with a bunch of live applications. So I want to make sure before proceeding. I didn't try. I can always make it foreignkey and nullable. But if it is unsigned, will it go with nullable. Thats what bothering me.

Comment: Make a copy of the database and try it there. That's what staging and testing enviroments are for.

Comment: Okay, will try it and let you know.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Works fine.